# How to exclude a dependency from being downloaded?

Tags: python, archlinux

Trying to install a lot of packages at the same time and get this error at the end of the download:

```
error: failed to commit transaction (conflicting files)
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/magic/__init__.py exists in both 'python-magic' and 'python-filemagic'
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/magic/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-310.opt-1.pyc exists in both 'python-magic' and 'python-filemagic'
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/magic/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-310.pyc exists in both 'python-magic' and 'python-filemagic'
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

How to exclude one of the 2 packages that are conflicting to complete the download successfully?

(Both "python-filemagic" and "python-magic" are not packages that I am trying to download. I assume they are dependencies, but I cannot figure out of which package am trying to download.)

[image: errorImage]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed it by adding the argument `--overwrite`

`sudo pacman -Syyu --needed --overwrite='*' <wanted-package>`